# Are there any precise design principles for artificial connectomes or neural networks?

Tags: computational-modeling, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, connectionism

I've been reading about the [openworm.org](http://openworm.org) project. I've downloaded the code and run some simulations.

The people at OpenWorm have made an experiment where they setup a robot with the neural network of the worm, obtaining very interesting results: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_i1NKPzbjM

It appears this could prove intelligent behavior, at least for rather simple organisms, is "coded" withing the structure of the neurons and the connections between them, ie. the connectome.

The first part of my question is: do we know why this particular connectomes work like they do, meaning we know how to design a connectome from scratch for a particular purpose? Or are we still in the phase of cloning/copying existing connectomes and study their emergent properties?

Depending on the first part, the second would be: are there any connectomes design principles regarding the construction of an artificial connectome/neural network for a given purpose?

Thanks!